# Script reads only even lines of file

Tags: c

I have a script in C that reads a file structured in lines like this:

```
1,example,2,3;
2,exampl,3,5;
3,examp,7,4;
4,exam,9,1;
```

And the script is here:

```
while(fscanf(fptr,"%d,%[^/,],%d,%s", &m[i].id,m[i].nojm,&m[i].salar,m[i].phon) != EOF) {

        fscanf(fptr,"%d,%[^/,],%d,%s;", &m[i].id,m[i].nojm,&m[i].salar,m[i].phon);
        printf("%d,%s,%d,%s\n", m[i].id,m[i].nojm,m[i].salar,m[i].phon);
    i++;
}
```

The problem I have is, that it reads only even lines of the file (2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th)...

How should I edit the code so it would read all lines?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE1:**

```
void nacti(emp *p,int n)
{

        FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("ulozka.txt","r");
    if(fptr==NULL){
      printf("Error opening file!");   
      getchar();             
   }

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char nojm[32];
    int salar;
    char phon[32];
} data_t;

          int i = 0;
    data_t m[4];
    while(fscanf(fptr,"%d,%[^/,],%d,%s", &m[i].id,m[i].nojm,&m[i].salar,m[i].phon) != EOF) {
        printf("%d,%s,%d,%s\n", m[i].id,m[i].nojm,m[i].salar,m[i].phon);
        i++;
    }

    printf("%d,%s,%d,%s\n", m[4].id,m[4].nojm,m[4].salar,m[4].phon);
    //printf("%d",pocet);

}
```

If there is only m[4], the code will only read 4 lines of the file? How should I edit it to read "indefinit" number of lines?

Comment: You have two calls to `fscanf()` in each loop. Delete the second one.

Comment: `%s;` --> `%[^;]`, `m[4]` : out of bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be replaced with the following:

```
while(fscanf(fptr,"%d,%[^/,],%d,%s", &m[i].id,m[i].nojm,&m[i].salar,m[i].phon) != EOF) {
    printf("%d,%s,%d,%s\n", m[i].id,m[i].nojm,m[i].salar,m[i].phon);
    i++;
}
```

The `fscanf` call in the while loop condition will be executed every loop iteration, so you don't need to call it again inside the loop.

**UPDATE**:

The following solution works for me. [You can try it here](http://ideone.com/5a2Xd6).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char nojm[32];
    int salar;
    char phon[32];
} data_t;

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    data_t m[4];
    while(fscanf(stdin,"%d,%[^/,],%d,%s", &m[i].id,m[i].nojm,&m[i].salar,m[i].phon) != EOF) {
        printf("%d,%s,%d,%s\n", m[i].id,m[i].nojm,m[i].salar,m[i].phon);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing the reason you're receiving a runtime error is that the character arrays you're using for strings (`nojm` and `phon`) are not long enough to process some of the entries in your text file, so memory is getting overwritten. Try increasing whatever length you're using to make sure it's greater than the longest string you'll encounter in your text file.

Another possibility is that you don't have enough items in your array to read in all the data from the text file. Here, I have a static array of 4 items to support the 4 from the text file. If your text file contains, say, 10,000 items you need to make sure you've properly allocated memory to store all of that.

Comment: I tried that, when I deleted the fscanf inside the loop, it gives me a bug (I started using MS visual studio just a few days ago and I don't know what "bug id" or something should I copy here so you can see it...)

Comment: What's the bug? How does it manifest itself? Do you mean you're unable to compile, or you don't get the results you expect?

Comment: Yes, I'm unable to compile.

Comment: When I deleted i++;, the code started working normally, but doesn't store the data into variables as it should (when the i doesnt get any value...). Do you know why?

Comment: @efeffi19 how can he know? He can't see through your pc :P Maybe the example I updated might help.

Comment: Also the example aardvarkk posted right now is nice, +1! :)

Comment: @efeffi19 This is now an entirely different question. You'll have to read up on dynamic memory allocation in C. Basically, you'll want to allocate a new struct every time you successfully read a new line. In my personal opinion, this is the area where C++ really begins to shine (if you have access to that instead).

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
while(fscanf(fptr,"%d,%[^/,],%d,%s", &m[i].id,m[i].nojm,&m[i].salar,m[i].phon) != EOF) {

    fscanf(fptr,"%d,%[^/,],%d,%s;", &m[i].id,m[i].nojm,&m[i].salar,m[i].phon);
    printf("%d,%s,%d,%s\n", m[i].id,m[i].nojm,m[i].salar,m[i].phon);
    i++;
}
```

So you:

1. read with `fscanf()`
2. read with `fscanf()`
3. print what you read

As a result you print only what the second fscanf read. Delete the second one and you should be fine.

So, your code should be like this:

```
while(fscanf(fptr,"%d,%[^/,],%d,%s", &m[i].id,m[i].nojm,&m[i].salar,m[i].phon) != EOF) {
    printf("%d,%s,%d,%s\n", m[i].id,m[i].nojm,m[i].salar,m[i].phon);
    i++;
}
```

---

I see that you have problems compiling your code. I suspect that your code is relevant to my example, it might help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Define the struct before main. */
struct person {
  char phon[20];
  int id;
};

// Give a synonym. Now struct person is the same with person_t.
typedef struct person person_t;

int main(void) {
  person_t array[3]; // can hold 3 persons
  FILE* fptr = NULL;
  fptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  int i = 0;
  while (fscanf(fptr, "%d, %s", &array[i].id, array[i].phon) != EOF) {
    printf("%d, %s\n", array[i].id, array[i].phon);
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and the test.txt

```
1, 697555555
2, 697888888
3, 694777777
```